# Export last windows update to CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, report

I am currently trying to export the results from the following to a CSV

```
    $windowsUpdateObject = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate
    $windowsUpdateObject.Results
```

What is the best way to add this to a report for all the PC's it runs on, then export it to a CSV?

So far my script looks like this

```
$machines = Get-Content 
C:\Users\******\Documents\Scripts\Last_Update\Machine_List.txt
$report = @()
$object = @()

    foreach ($machine in $machines ) 
{ 
    $windowsUpdateObject = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate
    $windowsUpdateObject.Results
    $report += $results
}

$report | Export-csv 'C:\Reports\Reboot.csv'
```

Comment: Are you looking for the Cmdlet [Add-Content](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156791.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the complete result from `$windowsUpdateObject.Results` stored in a variable with each iteration. 
But I am not seeing anywhere in the *foreach* code that you have mentioned the machine name. So its fetching the information locally (Iteration is happening based on the number of machines present in the file. But content fetching is happening locally).

You should use *[Invoke-Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)* in order to run that in the remote system.

I made the modifications for storing the result.

```
$machines = Get-Content "C:\Users\******\Documents\Scripts\Last_Update\Machine_List.txt"
$report = @()
$object = @()

foreach ($machine in $machines ) 
{ 
    $windowsUpdateObject = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate
    $report += $windowsUpdateObject.Results
}

$report | Export-csv 'C:\Reports\Reboot.csv' -Append -Force
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works great, Do you know however how I can add the PCname it obtained the data from onto the CSV?

Comment: You can remove the `$report = @()` line and explicitly cast as array within the loop: `[array]$report += $windowsUpdateObject.Results`